# .net - lock on boxed value instead of new object

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, value-type

I recently ran across this code in one of the projects I'm working on, and I'm not sure how it is supposed to behave.

```
private static object _syncRoot = 1;

public void DoSomething()
{
    lock (_syncRoot)
    {
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

I know that it's customary to use `new object()` for your lock.  How will this lock behave being locked on a boxed integer?  What happens if you add another lock with the same value?

```
private static object _anotherLock = 1;

public void DoSomethingElse()
{
    lock (_anotherLock)
    {
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not directly related to boxing, this could break if a string like "1" were used instead of an int.  Two strings with the same constant value can have the same reference and therefore locking on the 'separate' strings would use the same sync block.  In general, I would recommend new object() [a known good pattern] over a constant like this.

In fact, I'm not sure if boxing to unique instances is actually in the spec.  I could certainly see creating a 'boxing pool' for common constants (Like 0 or 1) as a potential CLR improvement.  If that were implemented, this usage would fail (in a quite nasty and unpredictable way, most likely.)

Answer (score 3):

`lock` always uses reference equality.

Two different boxed `1`s give two different locks.

Answer (score 1):

The second value will be boxed into a different object. The locks will be totally independant of each other because they reference two different objects.

Answer (score 0):

This will not lock the `1`, it cannot so in brief the boxed objects will be different and these locks will be different.

There is a reason why ValueTypes cannot be locked.